# Select QMessageBox stored as local variable for QTest

Tags: c++, qt, qtestlib

I'm trying to test with QTest a GUI application. I can access to all the UI elements across the `ui_class.h`. The problem is, that I've created several QMessageBox on the main program as local variable and I need them to use `QTest::mouseClick()` when anyone of them appears.

I'm trying to avoid to realocate those QMessageBox if possible, so I tried to get the Widgets with `QApplication::topLevelWidgets()` and `QApplication::allWidgets()`, but they were not working because I cannot find any `QWidget` which inheriths to `QMessageBox`. Neither is working `QApplication::activeWindow()` to make click (or press enter, I just wanna go further after clicking or pressing enter).

So, I would need to know how to select that `QMessageBox` stored as local variable on my GUI application I'm testing, to select it as `QWidget`.

My stored variables are `QMessageBox::StandardButton` and `QMessageBox::warning`

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show more code, please?
It's not clear: do you use

```
QMessageBox(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
```

constructor or something else. May be you might use `obj->findChild<T>(name)` or `qobject_cast()`? If you post your code I may try to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after trying something else and getting another problem, the easiest workaround for this was to declare all the `QMessageBox` on the header function as public, so I can access them through the `QTest` class.
That's the problem of using static messages.